# Auth0 Custom Social Connections Extension not work with Twitch?

Tags: reactjs, auth0, twitch

Now, I am creating Twitch Apps with React-Redux.

I just have a authentication problem with Auth0.

```
import auth0 from 'auth0-js';

export default class Auth {
    constructor() {
        this.popupTwitch = this.popupTwitch.bind(this)
    }

    auth0 = new auth0.WebAuth({
        domain: 'XXX.auth0.com',
        clientID: XXX,
        redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000/callback',
        audience: 'https://XXX.auth0.com/userinfo',
        responseType: 'token id_token',
        scope: 'openid'
    });

    popupTwitch() {
        this.auth0.popup.authorize({
            connection: 'twitch'
        })
    }
}
```

When I run this code, auth0 returns following error.

```
http://localhost:3000/?error=redirect_mismatch&error_description=Parameter+redirect_uri+does+not+match+registered+URI&state=XXX
```

My settings screenshots are below.

[Twitch Developer Dashboard Apps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWQce.png)

[Auth0 Custom Social Connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIBGx.png)

Thanks for your helping in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you'll need to set the twitch callback to redirect to auth0, not localhost.
The domain needed can be found in the settings for your auth0 client: https://manage.auth0.com/#/clients

Hope that helps :)

Comment: I try to change twitch redirect uri.   I can reach to twitch authorize page. `https://passport.twitch.tv/authorizations/new?client_id=xxx&login=xxx&redirect_uri=https://xxx.auth0.com/login/callback&response_type=code&scope=openid+channel_editor+channel_read&state=xxx`  When I click agree , 401 error is occured.

Comment: it looks like you're using auth0 scope in the twitch url. 
You'll need to change the scope to be `user_read` for a successful login

Comment: Thanks. I changed to `user_read`, it redirected to callback uri with access_token in fragment. But When I use this access_token, twitch returns  "invalid access_token".Is this token not for twitch ?